# Django: ImportError: No module named tinymce

Tags: python, django, heroku, tinymce

When executes the command: `Heroku run python manage.py syncdb` I get the message: `ImportError: No module named tinymce`

I use Django 1.6.2, TinyMCE: django-tinymce==1.5.2
That's what I did to install the TinyMCE:

I installed: `pip install django-tinymce`

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

django.contrib import from admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^', include ('app.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce /', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url (r'^admin /', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'tinymce',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join (base_dir, 'static')
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(base_dir, 'templates'),
)

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins' :'table, spellchecker, paste, searchreplace"
    'theme' : "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup ':True ,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels':10 ,
}
```

and performed `collectstatic` command.

I could not import the file models.py module tinymce:

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
```

Please for help.

Comment: Are you sure tinymce was correctly installed? You can check all installed apps by 'pip freeze'.

Comment: My "pip freeze":
`Django==1.6.2
South==0.8.4
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-tinymce==1.5.2
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.2
pystache==0.5.3
static==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2`

Comment: Hi, what about just importing tinymce. Does that work as well?

Comment: That does not work import, and after sending on Heroku gets "Internal server error".

Comment: This doesn't work locally or does not work on Heroku? If Heroku, did you add django-tinymce to your requirements.txt and re-deploy?

Comment: @DanHoerst Thanks for help. I didn't do: pip freeze > requirements.txt.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Dan Hoerst response in the comments, adding "django-tinymce" to the requirements.txt, commit, and then re-deploy solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

installing tinymce with `pip install django-tinymce` works!